# Masculine singular instrumental -ом, -ем, -ём

Tags: узус

I'm a little confused... When does one use each of the three endings in the title for nouns?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are variations of the same suffix in complementary distribution, depending on the preceding consonant and stress.

- *-ом* is used after hard (non-palatalized) consonants, except *ц, ш, ж*, anytime, and *ц, ш, ж, ч, щ* if stressed: *угло́м, го́дом, плечо́м, борщо́м*
- *-ем* is used after soft (palatalized) consonants (including implied *й*, that's after vowels and *ь* in writing) and hard *ц, ш, ж* if unstressed: *мо́рем, экипа́жем, со́лнцем, ду́шем, халде́ем, подспо́рьем*
- *-ём* is used after soft consonants (except *ч, щ*) if stressed: *конём, огнём, ружьём, холуём*

To put it more simply: *-ом* is hard, *-ем* is soft unstressed, *-ём* is soft stressed; but *ц, ч, ж, ш, щ* never work with *ё* in that position.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're presumably talking of 2nd declension, which includes both neuter gender and masculine ending in -о -е or "zero" grammatical ending.

The rule of thumb is like this:

> **-о** --> **-ом**
>   **-е** --> **-ем**
>   **-й** --> **-ем**
>   **-ь** --> **-ём**
>   anything else --> **-ом**

Yet take this as a hint, not as a strict rule.

Answer (score 1):

Существительные мужского рода единственного лица с пустым окончанием:творительный падеж единственного числа. Окончания -ом/-ем. Окончание -ом появляется всегда, если слово не оканчивается на шипящую или букву ц:

- баран - творить бараном
- стол - творить столом.

В случае если слово оканчивается на шипящую или ц, то существует два варианта:
ударение не падает на окончание. В таком случае окончание -ем:

- сторож - творить сторожем
- душ - творить душем

ударение падает на окончание.

В таком случае окончание -ом:

- плащ - творить плащом
- грош - творить грошом.

Итого, строки описания:

- молот → молотом
- месяц → месяцем

Comment: Что значит выражение "единственное лицо"? Возможно имелось ввиду слово "число"?