# What is the internal distribution of -ов/-ёв/-ев in the genitive plural and ой/-ёй/-ей in the instrumental singular?

Tags: существительные, морфология

If we disregard those nouns whose genitive plural ending is zero, -ей, or -ий, are the rules for which vowel letter to use in the genitive plural ending -ов/-ёв/-ев the same as the rules for which vowel letter to use in the instrumental singular ending -ом/-ём/-ем (as described in [https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12018/masculine-singular-instrumental-ом-ем-ём](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12018/masculine-singular-instrumental-%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%91%D0%BC))?

Are the rules for which vowel letter to use in the а-declension instrumental singular ending ой/-ёй/-ей the same?

Answer (score 1):

The endings for feminine nouns in the instrumental case (with the exeption of those ending in -ь) are: -ой after hard consonants and -ей after soft consonants or vowels:
Культура — культурой
Пенсия — пенсией
Няня — няней, дядя — дядей
When you have (ь), just add -ю:

(радость) → с радостью
But:

1. After ж, ш, ч, щ и ц the endings depend on the stress (-о́й stressed, -ей unstressed)

(учи́тельница) — работает учи́тельницей.
(хрипотца́) → голос с хрипотцо́й.
Птица — птицей
Ленцá — с ленцóй

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the rules for vowel distribution are exactly the same in those endings, as well as other endings e.g. neuter nominative -о/-е/-ё (ведро, поле, копьё), adjectival -ого/-его/-ёго, -ому/-ему/-ёму and suffixes:

- дуб**ов**ый, коричн**ев**ый, вишн**ёв**ый